# extracting numbers from string using regex

Tags: java, regex, string, match

I have a html code below, and with java i need to extract the numbers "25.12" as well as 8, 15, 17 etc. to store them inside array. Cant figure the proper regEx syntax.

```
<td align=center class="mazs" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#B5DA70">25.12</td>    
<td align=center class="mazs" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#B5DA70">8</td>
<td align=center class="mazs" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#B5DA70">15</td>
<td align=center class="mazs" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#B5DA70">17</td>
<td align=center class="mazs" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#B5DA70">18</td>
<td align=center class="mazs" rowspan="2" bgcolor="#B5DA70">20</td>
```

Comment: Java is not up to the task of parsing HTML. Look into JSoup (http://jsoup.org)

Answer (score 0):

read line by line from the file, then:

```
String yourValue = line.replaceAll("<[^>]*>","");
```

be careful, using regex to "parse" html is not the right way. For example, if there was line breaks in your html codes, the regex replace will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it in 1 line:

```
String[] numbers = str.replaceAll("<.*?>", " ").trim().split("\\s+");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/woKEaO).

Answer (score -1):

If all the lines are individually occurring and there is no variation, you can use a very simple regex as follows and get `Matcher.group(1)`:

```
>(.*)<
```

Comment: `(\d+)` == only digits, and at least one. Include x.x == `(\d+(\.\d+)?)`

Comment: Why the downvote? The op has clearly posted a sample of the html he has. Moreover, I have mentioned that this will work if there is no variation from the sample. There is no need to filter out only digits or at least one character. The answer is purely for this question and I have nowhere claimed that it would work for other similar situations. Just coz you can downvote doesn't give you the right to do so.

Comment: The mention of _"no need to filter out only digits"_ implies it's me you are asking "Why the downvote?" — I did not downvote. That said, the fact that you _can_ downvote does, exactly, give you the right to do so. I think your answer can be said to be "correct", in that it's not exactly wrong, but it's very imcomplete ... as the downvote button says, "This answer is not useful". Yet I still didn't downvote it.

Comment: Oh, I thought, it was in fact you who down voted. It's now even more ridiculous that someone did downvote, but did not mention any reason to do so. That said, my answer is complete for the question posted. I agree that it can be extrapolated to include much more factors, but so can 90% of the answers. If I ask a question, I'd be looking for the answer to that question, not how 20 additional problems related to my question can also be solved! :)